# how to upload encrypted file to google drive

Tags: android

I want to upload a database(sqlite) file to  google drive account.But I do not know how to upload a file to Google drive.pls provide some codes or link which may help  to upload a file from my internal/external storage to google drive.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot post a comment I would post this as an answer. Hope that it's not against community guidelines. But can't you just use an intent to ask the user to select Google Drive if installed (if the user wants to upload it to their own drive space,but you've not provided any info on that).

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setData(uriToFile).setType(mimeType);
startActivity(intent);
```

How to make the valid URI;

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDIrectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+stringPathToFile;
Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
```

Use this instead of Uri.parse(String).

Comment: ,I have tried with this code but when i choose google drive option from chooser "upload was unsuccessful,request contains no data".here is my code 'Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setData(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/database_copy.db")).setType("file/*");
     
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose one"));'

Comment: Try selecting Bluetooth option to see whether it fails too. If that one fails too there's something wrong with the code. I too had this problem somewhere but I don't remember exactly where and what my solution was.

Comment: ,facing same problem.

Comment: Make a log and see if new File(path).exists() returns true or false. I cant think of anything else. Hopefully someone else will answer.